# Using Pageable with Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data

I have a path that is necessary inform page, size, offset etc so I put a  *Pageable* in method parameters:

Controller

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Autowired))
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/orders")
public class OrderController {


    private final @lombok.NonNull OrderService orderService;

    @GetMapping()
    public ResponseEntity<Page<Order>> getOrdersByFilter(@RequestParam(value = "start", required = false) Date start,
                                                         @RequestParam(value = "end", required = false) Date end,
                                                         @RequestParam(value = "status", required = false) StatusType status,
                                                         @RequestParam(value = "delayed", required = false) Boolean delayed,
                                                         Pageable page) {
        OrderValidator.filtersAreValid(start, end, status, delayed);
        PedidoStatus orderStatus = StatusConverter.toDomain(status);
        Page<OrderES> orders = orderService.getOrdersByFilter(start, end, orderStatus, delayed, page);

        if (orders != null && !orders.getContent().isEmpty()) {
            Page result = new PageImpl(OrderESConverter.listToInterface(orders.getContent()), orders.getPageable(), orders.getTotalElements());
            return new ResponseEntity<>(result, HttpStatus.OK);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

I sent a request with Postman to application (*localhost:8080/app/v1/orders?status=CANCELED&page=1&size=10*) and received a *NoSuchMethodException*

Error

```
{
    "timestamp": 1526309013493,
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "No primary or default constructor found for interface org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable",
    "path": "/app/v1/orders"
}
```

Details

```
2018-05-14 11:43:33.469 ERROR 10406 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet]      : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/app/v1] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No primary or default constructor found for interface org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable] with root cause

java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable.<init>()
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
```

The biggest problem is: OrderController needs a orderService bean so I can't create a default constructor with no parameters and let orderService being null.

Configuration

```
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"br.com.app.models.interfaces", "br.com.app.models.domains"})
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"br.com.app.api.*"})
@EnableJpaRepositories
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableSpringDataWebSupport
public class OrderApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext applicationContext = SpringApplication.run(OrderApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

pom.xml (orders-api)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>br.com.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>orders-api</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>orders-api</name>
    <description>Orders API</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>br.com.app</groupId>
            <artifactId>app-models</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>br.com.apputils</groupId>
            <artifactId>api-utils</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!--<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>-->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <requiresUnpack>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>br.com.app</groupId>
                            <artifactId>app-models</artifactId>
                        </dependency>
                    </requiresUnpack>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>8</source>
                    <target>8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

pom.xml (apputils)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>br.com.apputils</groupId>
    <artifactId>api-utils</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>api-utils</name>
    <description>Utils classes for APIs development</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>br.com.app</groupId>
            <artifactId>app-models</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>8</source>
                    <target>8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

pom.xml (app-models)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>br.com.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>app-models</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.13.Final</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.4</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

What I can do?

Comment: I've created a spring-boot app with all the details provided but haven't been able to reproduce the problem, so far it is working. Is the error occurring when you actually run the app, or does it occur when running a test? My guess is either PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver is not being registered or there are conflicting versions of spring-data on the classpath. Not sure it matters but what version of projectlombok are you using?

Comment: @trf I'm using org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.20

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem. Like `Kimosabe` said, it's a Swagger problem. I fixed by adding the swagger resources on the resource handler. Apparently, Springfox Swagger and Spring Boot 2 has some issues. Here is the class:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2;

@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("swagger-ui.html")
        .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");

        registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**")
        .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

you should use the [@PagebleDefault](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/web/PageableDefault.html) annotation, e.g

```
public ResponseEntity<Page<Order>> getOrdersByFilter(@RequestParam(value = "start", required = false) Date start,
                                                     @RequestParam(value = "end", required = false) Date end,
                                                     @RequestParam(value = "status", required = false) StatusType status,
                                                     @RequestParam(value = "delayed", required = false) Boolean delayed,
                                                     @PageableDefault(size = 10, direction = Sort.Direction.DESC, sort = "someField") Pageable page) {
```

Comment: Please explain why should he do that?

Comment: You're right, i answer too quickly, and though it was the default missing, i'll update my answer.
In fact the "EnableSpringDataWebSupport" annotation should be enought to get Pageable resolved

Answer (score 1):

This is the Swagger problem, [see this](https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/755).

I did this for my project:

```
    @GetMapping("/orders")
    public ResponseEntity getAllOrders(@RequestParam(value = "page", defaultValue = "0", required = false) Integer page,
                                       @RequestParam(value = "size", defaultValue = "30", required = false) Integer size,
                                       @RequestParam(value = "sort", defaultValue = "orderNumber", required = false) String sort) {
        return execute(() -> service.getAllOrders(PageRequest.of(page, size, ASC, sort)));
    }
```

Hope it helps you.